# What is SOP (or what are some SOPs) for creating html layout - ultimately for Google App Engine(Python)

Tags: django, google-app-engine, grid

What are some accepted practices for dealing with headers and button bars and other elements/widgets; mostly referring to the html part - size of static sections on the page?  I'm using djangoforms, template_values passed to base.html and {% extends "base_generic.html" %}.

I'm a fairly handy programmer, but very HTML stupid.  Are we really talking about having all the layout (say the side bar where an ad might be, or a button bar across the top of all pages) laid out with   and so on with invisible grids embedded within invisible grids.  This seems to be what docs tell you to do, but google app engine docs are...there is room for improvement.

If that's what we're doing, are there accepted practices other than vim for creating these layouts?  Are there IDEs for this kind of thing.  Does CSS fit into these 'layout' methods as far as size of a grid space or just the rules, such as centered or not?

Do my questions reveal a deeper misundertanding?  Please suggest keywords I can use in google or GOOD documentation that won't assume I'm a Ruby or Java person just migrating over.

Comment: "Are there IDEs for this kind of thing."  There's always Dreamweaver  ;)

Answer (score 0):

The platform, whether its Ruby, Java or GAE, has absolutely nothing to do with the eventual HTML layout. This is done completely in HTML and CSS.

Grids are a good way to do this - there are several freely-available grid systems, such as http://960.gs/. These deal with the CSS, and also help you to generate the basic structure of your HTML.